# Who can view the membership of the group? via Powershell Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365

I would like to know how can I set who can view the membership of a group to "everyone" by using powershell in sharepoint online? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below code as a guide:

```
#Import the required DLL
Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
#OR
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'

#site URL
$site = 'https://Domain.sharepoint.com/'

#Admin User Principal Name
$admin = 'Admin@yourdomain.com'

#Get Password as secure String
$password = Read-Host 'Enter Password' -AsSecureString

#Get the Client Context and Bind the Site Collection
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)

#Authenticate
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($admin , $password)
$context.Credentials = $credentials

$web = $context.Web;
$grp = $web.SiteGroups.GetByName("name");
$context.Load($grp);
$grp.OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership = $false;
$grp.Update();
$context.ExecuteQuery();
```

**Ref:**https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29518.csom-sharepoint-powershell-reference-and-example-codes.aspx

**Ref:**https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.group_members.aspx